# Line through text with shadow under the text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to add a text with a line through it, like the css `text-decoration: line-through`. However, I also want the text and the line to have a shadow under them, but the line's shadow passes over the text:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0XGN.png)

Is there any way to make the line go above the text but the line's shadow go under the text? Any JavaScript and CSS can be used to accomplish this effect. I would like no jQuery, but it may also be used if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with pseudo elements and a box-shadow but wrapping text would ruin it

here's an example:

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #444;
}
.shadow-text {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
.shadow-text::after, .shadow-text::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.1em;
}
.shadow-text::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
.shadow-text::before {
    content: '';
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 0px black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-text">You have weird tastes</div>
```

Comment: This works to solve the question I made and originally solved my problem, but in the end I ended up having to wrap the text

Comment: I just made the internal wrappers also use that CSS, since they're always going to be the same wrappers. It worked great, thanks